# How to implement checkbox over GridView correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout, future

I have checkbox for selecting and deselecting photos.
There is a visible loading screen for each tap.

[image: Visible loading screen]

`_mediaList` has the photo asset. `mediaModel` has the necessary methods to add and remove the path of selected and deselected photos respectively.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: _mediaList.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3, mainAxisSpacing: 4.0, crossAxisSpacing: 4.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final saved = mediaModel.getMedia().contains(
            _mediaList[index].relativePath + '/' + _mediaList[index].title);
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: _mediaList[index].thumbDataWithSize(200, 200),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                ? GridTile(
                    header: saved
                        ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white,)
                        : Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline, color: Colors.white,),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.memory(
                          snapshot.data,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        onTap: () => setState(() => saved
                            ? mediaModel.removeMedia(
                                _mediaList[index].relativePath +
                                    '/' +
                                    _mediaList[index].title)
                            : mediaModel.addMedia(
                                _mediaList[index].relativePath +
                                    '/' +
                                    _mediaList[index].title))),
                  )
                : Container());
      },
    );
  }
```

**EDIT**: After some analysis, I found out using `Provider` to load images might be the right way.

Can you help me in converting this code to `Provider`?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```
class FooPage extends State<SoPage> {
  static const int _count = 10;
  final List<bool> _checks = List.generate(_count, (_) => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: _count,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Container(color: Colors.red[(i * 100) % 900]),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Checkbox(
                  value: _checks[i],
                  onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _checks[i] = newValue),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This implementation also gives the same result. Is it because of `FutureBuilder`?             
 And I need to change the checkbox by tapping the photo.

Comment: @shanthosh Can you post a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour only when dealing with images `Image.memory()`. You can use this code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mc68BZx7YR/. I think this is happening because of changing the state of whole list instead of only checkbox.

Comment: @shanthosh I ran the code and it was working fine. In the code you were using `ListView`

Comment: Yes I'm using `ListView`. You can see the app icons flicker when checkbox is tapped.